# Why the is the new dataframe not found?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I'm trying reproduce code from someones study. So far I'm only trying to break down the function  that reshapes the date into individual pieces to understand what it does exactly. When trying to create a new dataframe called 'datarule' based on the original 'data', i get "Error: object 'datarule' not found". What is going on in there? Probably a trivial thing, but would appreciate your help with this.

**Here is my the R code:**

```
data$test = as.logical(data$test) #convert 'test' col to boolean type True/False

max_learn_block <- max(data[!data$test, "block"])
data <- data %>%
  mutate(block=ifelse(test, max_learn_block+1, block))

datarule <- data %>% 
  mutate(block=block+1) %>% 
  
head(datarule)
```

**Here is the original function code:**

```
  if (combine_test) {
    max_learn_block <- max(data[!data$test, "block"])
    data <- data %>%
      mutate(block=ifelse(test, max_learn_block+1, block))
  }
  datarule <- data %>%
    mutate(block=block+1) %>%
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lines at the end of your code are

```
datarule <- data %>% 
  mutate(block=block+1) %>% 

head(datarule)
```

Since the 2nd line ends with a pipe operator `%>%`, the last line is taken to be part of the whole expression.  But `datarule` hasn't been created yet, so you get the error you saw.

To fix this, just leave off the `%>%` pipe at the end of the 2nd line.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on what you are doing.

Try just doing

```
    datarule <- data %>% 
         mutate(block=block+1) 
    head(datarule)
```

The issue is most likely that you are referencing `datarule` before it has been created. There also seems to be a hanging pipe operator (`%>%`) that is going nowhere. In the code above, you first create `datarule` by mutating `data`, then the second line prints out the first six rows

Comment: Thanks for help, i'm new to r so I'm still learning the syntax. Isn't "datarule <- data" creating the datarule structure, so that I could' reference it after that? If not what is it?
When I will be adding code to further modify the datarule dataframe how could I save it to csv files to see the status of modifications?

Comment: @jpsmith:  it's too long for a comment, and it's impossible to put the multi-line code in a comment.

Comment: @peter:  No, the expression being evaluated in your code is `data %>% 
  mutate(block=block+1) %>% head(datarule)`.  The whole thing gets evaluated before `datarule` is created.  Except it can't, because it uses `datarule`, which doesn't exist yet.